# bad operand types for binary operator '<' first type: float second type: Object

Tags: java

I want to make a simple Java program but I'm getting the following error:

```
bad operand types for binary operator '<'
  first type:  float
  second type: Object
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList pa = new ArrayList();
    pa.add(100);
    pa.add(85);
    pa.add(80);
    pa.add(75);
    pa.add(70);
    pa.add(60);
    pa.add(50);
    pa.add(40);

    int [] pb = new int[8]; 
    pb[0] =85;
    pb[1] =80;
    pb[2] =75;
    pb[3] =70;
    pb[4] =60;
    pb[5] =50;
    pb[6] =40;
    pb[7] =30;

    float input ;
    string grade;

        if ( (input < pa.get(1) ) && (input270 >= pb270[0]) ) // this is the problem
            {   grade = "A+";   
        }
```

Comment: error message is clear, isn't it?

Comment: yaps,, thank's for your help

Answer (score 1):

Define your collection so that it has type information rather than using a [raw type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html)

```
List<Integer> pa = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
ArrayList pa = new ArrayList();
```

to:

```
ArrayList<Integer> pa = new ArrayList<>();
```

or if you prefer:

```
ArrayList<Float> pa = new ArrayList<>();
```

Without telling it the type of the data in the list, it treats all elements as `Object`, and you cannot compare a `float` with an `Object` using the `<` operator.